# How can I fix "NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF$37D05B5"?

Tags: apt, gnupg

Best regards, I recently tried to open “Software” in Ubuntu Studio Disco Dingo 19.04, to search for an application and continuously issues the following message:

[image]

```
Unable to download updates:
failed to refresh cache: W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com lucid InRelease: the following signatures couldn`t be verified because the public key is not abvailable: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5"
```

Comment: Are you sure about *lucid* (lynx, 10.04 LTS)? What is your Ubuntu version? Was it a clean install or upgrade from 10.04 LTS?

Comment: open a shell/terminal/bash prompt and type  `lsb_release -a`, press enter, then copy the printed text into your posting.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems as though you added a PPA or repository that is looking for a "lucid" version of its repo, which is outdated. If you remove that repo/PPA from your repositories using the "Software and Updates" tool, you might be able to get past this.

"Lucid Lynx", aka 10.04, is long-since outdated.